# Older XCode namespace error

Tags: xcode, opencv

I moved an openCV application from a newer version of Xcode to an older one (3.2.1) and using the same code I'm getting quite a few errors from the start.

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
```

returns the following error : 'namespace undeclared here'

```
cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(10, 100, 100), cvScalar(20, 255, 255), imgThreshed);
```

returns the following error: 'Too few arguments to function 'cvscalar'

Anyone know why this may be? it all works fine on a recent XCode.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve by going back to Xcode 3?

Comment: I need to run the application on mac 10.6.8

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for explaining what you were trying to do.

Don't fight with older versions of Xcode (the shift from Xcode 3 to Xcode 4 was more dramatic than the shift from Xcode 4 to Xcode 5 is gonna be), but instead you can ***set*** the minimum deployment version for your application in your project settings.

Here's how it looks when I do this:

[image]

Comment: My mac is running snow leopard, am I able to run xcode 4 on it? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If you log in to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action you can find a copy of "XCode 4.2 for Snow Leopard".  You should be able to build with that.